# Typescript complains about function parameter type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have `FileUpload` component which takes function in order to create a functional component inside it. Typescript complains about the `onOpen` passed as a parameter to that function when I am trying to use it.

> Binding element 'onOpen' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
<FileUpload onChange={onFileSelect}>
  {({ onOpen }) => (    //<------- Error
    <Button onClick={() => onOpen()}>
      Upload image
    </Button>
  )}
</FileUpload>
```

I have tried many options to give it a type `() => void;` or similar but I just can't figure it out... Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sometimes, it is good to set `"noImplicitAny": false,` in `tsconfig` file. BTW, you can try `{({ onOpen }: {onOpen: () => void}) => <Button ....`

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code like this. This way you are declaring an interface defining the structure of parameters of the callback

```
interface FileUploadCallbackProps {
  onOpen: () => void;
}

<FileUpload onChange={onFileSelect}>
  {(props: FileUploadCallbackProps) => (
    <Button onClick={() => props.onOpen()}>Upload image</Button>
  )}
</FileUpload>;
```